# How to save after overlaying a spatial point data frame onto raster

Tags: r, plot, geospatial, raster, shapefile

I tried to overlay a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` (yellow birds) onto a `raster` data (map). This was successful with the following R codes:

```
map1 = plot(map)

overlay_map = plot(yellowbirds,add=TRUE,col="blue")
```

However, when I want to regenerate the map by typing `overlay_map`, the output produced is `Null` instead of giving me the map.

How do I save the above correctly as a variable, so that I can generate the map without typing out the code again?

Comment: try to type `plot(overlay_map)` what is the output?

Comment: Please read "How to ask" and use correct `code formating` in your text.

Comment: When I type `plot(overlay_map)`, I get `Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`recordPlot` is the right way to go, only that it saves the **current plot** (see [`?recordPlot`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.5.0/topics/recordPlot)) into a variable. I created this *reproducible example*:

```
library(raster)
map <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
yellowbirds <- SpatialPoints(
  coords = structure(c(179025.023681718, 179606.015156299, 179878.354910009, 
                       180441.19040101, 180913.245974108, 330055.067887591, 330508.967477108, 
                       331398.610672561, 331743.574360594, 332342.721818756), 
                     .Dim = c(5L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y"))))

plot(map)
map1 <- recordPlot()
plot(yellowbirds, add = TRUE)
overlay_map <- recordPlot()
```

[image]

Now we kill the current devices and reproduce the two plots:

```
dev.off()
map1
dev.off()
overlay_map
```

Both the `map` as well as the `overlay_map` should be recreated in the empty device. Even if you `rm(map1)`, `overlay_map` will plot correctly.

**NOTE:** Do not call `plot(overlay_map)` as it produces the following error

> `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
>     'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'`

Comment: This works fine when run together:

`plot(map)          
map1 <- recordPlot()      
plot(yellowbirds, add = TRUE)  
overlay_map <- recordPlot()`  

However, when I key `overlay_map` again, the output is a list of 3. And when I key `plot(overlap_map)`, the following error results:

`Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'`.

Comment: You do not have to call `plot(overlay_map)` as it produces the mentioned error. Just call `overlay_map` and the plot will be reproduced

Comment: When I call `overlay_map`, there is no output or error message.

Comment: Exactly, but there should be a plot

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a plot... the only change is that it appears in my R Environment. As a list of 3.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to help you without any reproducible example.

However, if you only want to save the plot,
you could do something like:

```
map1 <- plot(map)

overlay_map <- recordPlot()  #To save the next plot into an object

plot(yellowbirds,add=TRUE,col="blue")
```

Then, simply call the object again:

```
overlay_map
```

Comment: When I typed `overlay_map <- recordPlot()`, the error message faced was `Error in recordPlot() : no current device to record from`. 

Alternatively, I tried to run the three lines of codes, but the `overlay_map` did not produce any output.

Comment: Are you on RStudio?

Comment: Yes I am on RStudio.